# Prestashop 1.7 project setup

Tags: php, composer-php, prestashop

I'm new with Prestashop 1.7 and I have to continue a project that was created 1 year ago and is deployed in a shared server. I'm having trouble setting up the project in my computer. I downloaded all the files from the server, including the "vendor" directory.

First question, shouldn't exist in the root of the project a **composer.json**? I have a **composer.lock** but no **composer.json**. I work with Laravel for the past 6 years in a daily basis and found this weird so I assume the previous developer didn't upload the file to the server.

Secondly, and most important, when I try to access the project url (http://localhost:8001) exactly as I downloaded from the server and I run into the following error

```php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\ContainerBuilder' not found in /var/www/html/config/bootstrap.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/config/config.inc.php(57): require_once() #1 /var/www/html/index.php(27): require('/var/www/html/c...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/config/bootstrap.php on line 34
```

I triple checked that the **ContainerBuilder** exists and all the namespaces are correct. Also, I tried clear the "Classes cache" and I also tried to delete the **vendor** directory and reinstall it, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: test this: remove cache/class_index.php

Comment: @MahdiShad thanks for your suggestion but I already tried that 2 or 3 times and didn't solve the issue.